# ObjectMapper: параметризация

Tags: java, generics

У меня есть JSON, который нужно прочитать в объект при помощи ObjectMapper. Выглядит это так:

```
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Report<? extends BaseLog> toReport(String json) throws IOException {
        return mapper.readValue(json, Report.class);
}
```

При этом, IDEA ругается на параметризацию, мол, `Unchecked Assignment`, то есть, хочет от меня, чтобы `Report` был именно `<? extends BaseLog>`.

Вот так, как я понял, не получится:

```
Report<? extends BaseLog> toReport(String json) throws IOException {
        return mapper.readValue(json, Report<? extends BaseLog>.class);
}
```

Каким образом можно параметризировать объект при его маппинге?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html)

```
TypeReference<Report<? extends BaseLog>> type = new TypeReference<Report<? extends BaseLog>>() {};
mapper.readValue(json, type);
```